# Does it make it easier to crack the inner volume if the outer volume has an easy password? (VeraCrypt volume)

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

When you create an encrypted volume with VeraCrypt, you have an inner and an outer volume. If I make the other volume easy to crack with a short password, does that make the inner volume more vulnerable even if it has a long and complex password?

Comment: it should not matter if the outside is encrypted at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you don't have an inner and an outer volume. You have a standard and a hidden volume. Both are completely independent of each other regarding their encryption (see https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hidden%20Volume).